# Deployed to Heroku, admin UI login suddenly stops working

Tags: heroku, keystonejs

I recently initialized a Keystone app using the guide [here](https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/new-project). The only other thing I touched in the code was to add in a Next.js app on the frontend, and changed the mongodb connection string to point to my MongoDB Atlas cluster. I deployed this app on Heroku, it connects to the db and everything builds fine, but when trying to log in, after clicking 'Sign In' the button shows the loading indicator for a second and then just displays the login page again.

I've read through the docs and tried putting

```
config: {
    identityField: 'email',
    secretField: 'password'
  }
```

in my `authStrategy` definition, but to no avail. Really not sure where else to go from here.

Here's my `Keystone` definition:

```
const keystone = new Keystone({
  name: PROJECT_NAME,
  adapter: new Adapter({
    mongoUri: 'mongodb+srv://stratus:WjbsENMyBV80AJ6H@cluster0-qe4bs.azure.mongodb.net/stratus?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
    useNewUrlParser: true
  }),
});

// Access control functions
const userIsAdmin = ({ authentication: { item: user } }) => Boolean(user && user.isAdmin);
const userOwnsItem = ({ authentication: { item: user } }) => {
  if (!user) {
    return false;
  }
  return { id: user.id };
};
const userIsAdminOrOwner = auth => {
  const isAdmin = access.userIsAdmin(auth);
  const isOwner = access.userOwnsItem(auth);
  return isAdmin ? isAdmin : isOwner;
};
const access = { userIsAdmin, userOwnsItem, userIsAdminOrOwner };

keystone.createList('User', {
  fields: {
    name: { type: Text },
    email: {
      type: Text,
      isUnique: true,
    },
    isAdmin: { type: Checkbox },
    password: {
      type: Password,
    },
  },
  // To create an initial user you can temporarily remove access controls
  access: {
    read: access.userIsAdminOrOwner,
    update: access.userIsAdminOrOwner,
    create: access.userIsAdmin,
    delete: access.userIsAdmin,
    auth: true,
  },
});

const authStrategy = keystone.createAuthStrategy({
  type: PasswordAuthStrategy,
  list: 'User',
  config: {
    identityField: 'email',
    secretField: 'password'
  }
});

module.exports = {
  keystone,
  apps: [
    new GraphQLApp(),
    // To create an initial user you can temporarily remove the authStrategy below
    new AdminUIApp({ enableDefaultRoute: true, authStrategy }),
    new NextApp({ dir: 'client'})
  ],
};
```

I don't see any errors in my Heroku logs. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: find an answer to this? I am having the same issue

Comment: Kenny Hammerlund I updated this with the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was the in-memory session store, per the docs it doesn't scale past a single process. In production, this needs to be set in the `Keystone` constructor by passing in a key-value pair of `"session store": <Session Store>` as shown [in the docs](https://keystonejs.com/docs_configuration)

Comment: Thanks for the help, that pointed me in the right direction, there was another issue as well, Using v5 I needed to pass `secureCookies:false` to the constructor as I was using a free heroku dyno which didn't have ssl installed yet. 

Also your link is broken. were you trying to point to this? 
https://www.keystonejs.com/keystonejs/keystone/

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel pointed out, the in-memory session store does not scale. To remedy this I had to attach my mongoStore to the session store.

this is Keystone v5

```
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);

const keystone = new Keystone({
  name: PROJECT_NAME,
  adapter: new Adapter({
    mongoUri: process.env.MONGO_URL
  }),
  onConnect: initialiseData,
  cookieSecret: process.env.SESSION_KEY,
  secureCookies: false,  <-- needed on non-SSL servers
  sessionStore: new MongoStore({
    url: process.env.MONGO_URL
  })
});
```

connect-mongo
https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo

express-session https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session

Answer (score 0):

At the time of my deployment (March 2021), after implementing Kenny's suggestion, the secure cookies needs to be set to false by setting the `cookie.secure` property per [Keystone doc](https://www.keystonejs.com/keystonejs/keystone/#cookie)

```
const keystone = new Keystone({
  /* ...config */
  cookie: {
    secure: false // if SSL not enabled!
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, 
    sameSite: false,
  },
});
```